# Finding coordinates of line intersecting with a capsule and drawing a circle inside of the capsule at that point

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have a capsule shape which I know its A,B points and its radius in a 2D plane. I also know a line starts from the center of the capsule and goes in a direction. My goal is to find the intersection point of this line with the capsule boundaries, and draw a circle there with radius r. So what would be the coordinates of the r in 2d coordinates?

If the intersection point is in the rectangular area, I'm able to find it with hypothenus and I can find the coordinates of its center easily. But when it goes to side of the capsule, I'm not.

[image: Capsule Drawing]

Comment: Put your definitions in your drawing (height/width of the capsule and radius R of the sides). Choose an origin for an $xy$ system, in the center of the capsule would be nice. Then your line starting from the origin has a simple function $y=ax$, and the side of the capsule also has a simple function $(x-w/2)^2+y^2=R^2$ where $w$ is the distance between the centers of the 2 side circles. Make both functions equal and you get a solution for your 2D point.

Comment: Hi @JeroenBoschma. Thanks for the answer! I tried it and it works as expected. So, what about putting a circle with radius r and sweeps that point. How can I find it's center? Thanks again!

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you mean... My previous comment gives you the intersection point $(x_I,y_I)$ with the capsule. The centre of the small circle with radius $r$ is then on the line from the centre of the large circle (capsule end). So you have to make a function $y=ax+b$ for that line (you have two points of that, $(x,y)=(W/2,0)$ and $(x_I,y_I)$). Then  you find the point on that line which is $r$ away from $(x_I,y_I)$ with $(x_c-x_I)^2+(ax_c+b-y_I)^2=r^2$. That gives you $x_c$ as the x-coordinate of that centre, then get $y_c$ from your line equation $y=ax+b$. Bit complicated...

Comment: If you mean all circles with radius $r$ that touch the red dot in your drawing: their center is on a circle around that red dot with radius $r$. That can be found easily.

Comment: What are the "A, B points"? There are no points labelled A and B in your drawing. From your graph, I'm guessing $r$ is just some given value, not determined by anything else? What do you mean by "coordinates of the $r$"? $r$ is just a radius - a length. Points have coordinates, lengths do not. Apparently the circles are to be tangent to the capsule shape? (FYI - this is most commonly called a "logenze" - it is a very common shape in manufacturing, since it is easy to cut and has no corners where stresses can build up and cause cracks.)

Comment: Hi Paul. By A and B points I tried to mention center coordinates of two large circles. I've made a mistake by saying coordinates of r. I was trying to mention that I need to draw smaller circles with radius r who touches the point where my blue lines intersect with the capsule shape. I'm not sure if they can be tangent to the capsule though.